# Using Hazelcast, is it possible to get notified (only) when a distributed queue has items ready to be consumed?

Tags: java, queue, message-queue, hazelcast

Hazelcast comes with a distributed implementation of [BlockingQueue](http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#distributed-queue) that allows for blocking waits and polling of new items. However, this interface doesn't natively support callbacks for when new items are available to be consumed. There's also a [distributed topic](http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#distributed-topic) that does have a push based model, but does not support delayed "ack" of items the way a queue does with peek.

Is there any way to build a notifying queue with Hazelcast primitives?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it isn't available. But we are planning to release an async programming api in 3.3. So then you will have a mechanism for your callbacks. One of the fundamentals things that need to be in place for that is back pressure to prevent overloading the system with requests and that is something I'm going to work on in the 3.3 release.